# How to redirect from '/collections/all' to '/collections/shop-all' with Liquid or JS from Shopify

Tags: redirect, collections, path, shopify, reserved

I had a store on Shopify where I would like to know how can I redirect from '/collections/all' to '/collections/shop-all' with Liquid from Shopify. (But I already have read that you can't redirect from '/all' page, because is a reserved path).

I have a store where the less traffic data has "/shop-all" page and I would like to increase to this one where when the visitors click to my 'Shop' button's store, immediately the page redirects to "/collections/shop-all", no more to the "collections/all".

Is that possible? Who can I do that programming with Liquid or JavaScript code?
I await at your response.

Thanks

Try to redirect from '/collections/all' to '/collections/shop-all' with Liquid code.